# Block.io set smaller fees?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-fees, api, block.io

Is it possible to set a custom transaction fee with block.io? We are using their API and their "Low" fee is still far too high (currently $3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't suggest to use block.io since they will limit your number of your bitcoin addresses.

Any way they don't support custom fee.

**As on block.io site**

> Estimate network fee will be paid on withdrawal of given amounts

Comment: What alternative do you suggest? I don't really like blockchain.info - Ideally we would have our own BItcoin node but that maybe too difficult.

Comment: i'm afraid that there's no other alternatives.

Comment: But please consider that if the fee is too high it might be of your transactions.
Because transaction fee on most bitcoin wallet depends on your previous inputs(transactions)

Comment: Please check out my answer in here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/63607/why-is-the-mining-fee-so-high/63617#63617

Comment: Thanks but it's coming from one and their fee/kb is far too high. I guess ill have to go with blockchain.info - Do they allow custom fees and unlimited wallets? Also do they charge like block.io because I can't find any pricing. Also who would I use for LTC?

Comment: Blockchain is free  but they have many issues, Like you may miss callbacks.
And create wallet is unlimited but you can't create more than 20 empty address, because the blockchain will not scan these addresses as defined on bip44.

Comment: From blockchain: 
wallet software will not scan past 20 unused addresses. Given enough requests from this API that don't have a matching payment, you could generate addresses past this horizon, which would make spending funds paid to those addresses quite difficult. For this reason, this API will return an error and refuse to generate new addresses if it detects it would create a gap of over 20 unused addresses. If you encounter this error, you will either need to switch to a new xPub (within the same wallet is fine), or receive a payment to one of the previous 20 created addresses

Comment: Also you can't use it for LTC

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing that up. I think my only choice now is to get our own nodes wallet integrated. We may have hundreds possibly thousands of signups and each account must have their own wallet. 50% of which maybe empty. Do you see any problems we may face with Bitcoin/LTC nodes?

Comment: Own address not wallet.